# DbContext Remove generates DbUpdateConcurrencyException when DATETIME includes milliseconds

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-5.0

I have a "legacy" table that I'm managing in a webapp.  It uses a compound key, rather than an auto-increment integer, which I register during `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeLog>().HasKey(table => new { table.EmployeeID, table.DateCreated });
```

If it matters, the `EmployeeID` is a VARCHAR`` and `DateCreated` is a `DATETIME`.

When I attempt to delete a record:

```
...

// the UI stores the date/time without milliseconds, use a theta join to bracket the time
var model = await _context.EmployeeLogs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.EmployeeID == driverID && (l.DateCreated >= date && l.DateCreated < date.AddSeconds(1)));

_context.Remove(model);

var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get an error when `SaveChangesAsync` is called:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

The model is correctly identified and contains the expected data.

I appears that the issue is related to the granularity of the date.  If milliseconds are included, for example `2021-04-27 08:06:33.193`, then the error is generated.  If the date/time does not include milliseconds, `2021-04-27 08:06:33.000` for example, the deletion works correctly.

I can truncate milliseconds when creating the record, but I'd like to know if there is a way to handle this if the record already contains milliseconds.

** edit **

I don't have any control over the vendor's database decisions, so I need a solution that addresses that reality.

Comment: Don't use such a key. If you *absolutely* have to (**why?**), don't use `datetime`, use `datetime2` with a fixed precision. A `datetime` is a float whose fractional part represents the time in a 24 hour date, with a precision of 3.33 ms. Needless to say, it's imprecise. `datetime2(3)` will maintain the precision you specify BUT ... WHY?

Comment: For example, if you want to store historical data you can use a [temporal table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server. If you can't use them, *don't* store all versions in the same table. Right now you can't ensure there's only a single "current" employee record, or use `EmployeeID` in foreign key constraints.

Comment: Usually, I get such kind of error when context lifetime is mistreated. It is strange to see that it has to do something with types of table fields.

Comment: `I need a solution that addresses that reality.` the reality is that SQL Server's `datetime` doesn't have millisecond precision. Its resolution is 3.33. This means that unless the millisecond count is (roughly) a multiple of 3, it can't be represented.  `0.193` can't be represented with a `datetime`. You'll have to either change the type of the field to `datetime2(3)` at least, or *exclude* the `DateCreated` field from the entity's key. You may be able to map to a view that returns the "current" rows only.

Comment: Another, trickier option is to round the millisecond part of `DateCreated` to a multiple of 3.33ms. You may be able to do this with [DateTime.ToOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=net-5.0) and [FromOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=net-5.0). These methods convert a `DateTime` value to the same floating-point form used by SQL Server's `datetime`. In a new object `obj.DateCreated=DateTime.FromOADate(DateTime.Now.ToOADate())` *may* result in a value that won't be modified

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Don't you think that if you retrieve record from the database (regardless of how it is encoded), you should be able to delete it? Don't know about you, but I find it weird.

Comment: Of course if it is happening. Which I was not able to reproduce with the provided code. Needs [mcve].

Comment: I could reproduce the problem on my side, if the datetime contains the milliseconds, it will show the DbUpdateConcurrencyException when call the SaveChange method. I suggest you could feedback this issue to [EF Core Github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues). Besides, as a workaround, you could change change the datetime and remove the milliseconds. Or, you can refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency) and use the ExecuteSqlRaw method to execute a SQL command and delete the entity.